# Using Bernoulli's Distribution to find the number of tosses required such that the probability of getting no heads is equal to one

Tags: probability

We can find the number of tosses required such that the probability of getting atleast once is atleast 99% by solving the equation $1-$$n\choose{0}$$2^{-n}2^0≥0.99$ and we get that $n≥7$.

But why does this method not work when I try to find the number of tosses required for the probability of getting 0 heads to be equal to one or atleast 0.99 or for the probability of getting exactly one head to be atleast 0.99.

I.e,

$$P(H=0)=1$$ and $$P(H=1)≥0.99$$
For which why can't we use
$$
{n\choose{0}}2^02^{-n} = 1
$$
And
$$
{n\choose{1}}2^12^{-(n-1)} ≥ 0.99
$$

Comment: "...when I try to find the number of tosses required such that the probability of getting no heads to be equal to one or atleast 0.99 or for the probability of getting exactly one head to be atleast 0.99." I am confused about what you are asking.  Please try to **carefully** re-phrase your question so that I am not confused.

Comment: @user2661923 I want to know why does this method not work when I try to find the number of coin tosses required for the probability of getting zero heads become 1

Comment: The probability of getting zero heads never becomes $1$.  Please try again to re-phrase your question.

Comment: @user2661923 and that's exactly my question, I want to know the mathematical reason why. Why does the probability of getting zero heads never be 1

Comment: If you toss the coin once, the chance of no heads is $(1/2)$.  As the number of coin tosses increases to $n$ tosses, the chance of no heads **decreases** to $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{2^n},~$ rather than increases.  Therefore, the chance of no heads, after $n$ coin tosses is never larger than $(1/2)$, for $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$

Comment: @user2661923 thanks mate. So I have to check if the probability of an event decreases from it's individual probability if done in succession. This same argument can me made for why getting exactly one head probability will never be equal to 1 right? This is what I interned from your explanation

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @user2661923 thanks for the explanation. If you copy paste the comment as an answer I'll accept it and close the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per OP's (i.e. original poster's) request:

If you toss the coin once, the chance of no heads is $(1/2).$ As the number of coin tosses increases to $n$ tosses, the chance of no heads decreases to  $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{2^n},~$  rather than increases. Therefore, the chance of no heads, after $n$ coin tosses is never larger than $(1/2)$, for $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$

> This same argument can me made for why getting exactly one head probability will never be equal to 1 right?

Chance of $1$ head in $n$ tosses is $~\displaystyle P(n) = \frac{\binom{n}{1}}{2^n} ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.~$  $~P(1) = ~\displaystyle \frac{1}{2},~$ and as $n$ increases, $~P(n)~$ decreases.  Therefore, $P(n)$ never evaluates to $1$, for any $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$